# Shorts in Android and Java

Tags: java, android, short

I have written some code that used strings to represent time such as "0620", but after careful thought I realised these could be parsed into shorts for comparison performance and storage gains.

In a unit test, I have a short written as 0620 being compared against a return value of 620, expecting this to work. However, the test **0620 equals 620** (both are shorts) fails.

The error message says 0620 was interrupted as 400 (and 400 != 620 explaining the failure). Removing the lead 0 fixes the problem, but I wanted to know, what's going on with this?

***This doesn't work***

```
assertEquals("Time Failed", 0620, st.GetTime());
```

***This Works***

```
assertEquals("Time Failed", 620, st.GetTime());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An integer literal beginning with a `0` is interpreted as octal (base 8) as per the [Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII
>   digit 0 followed by one or more of the
>   ASCII digits 0 through 7 and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or
>   negative integer.

I believe this is one of the quirks Java inherited from C.

Answer (score 3):

0620 means octal(base 8) in java I guess it's the same in android  or 0620 == 400 not 620

```
     int decVal = 26;   // The number 26, in decimal
     int octVal = 032;  // The number 26, in octal
     int hexVal = 0x1a; // The number 26, in hexadecimal
```

[example from java tutorials at SUN/Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)